# How to force re-read XFS file system contents

Tags: centos7, filesystems, xfs

In our computing cluster we have set up a simple but quite effective way of serving data to computing nodes.

The storage system provides to luns that are merged with LVS and on top of that we build a big (80 TiB) XFS partition. All nodes are attached to the storage cabin and recognize LVS and the XFS with no problem. One node mounts XFS in read/write (RW) mode and the others in read-only (RO) mode.

Now, the thing is that whenever something new is written through the RW node, I have to remount XFS in the others so the new files are seen in the RO nodes. This operation is simple: just `umount` followed by a `mount`.

```
umount /data
mount /data
```

However this solution is not very good since this RO nodes may be reading data and the remounting may not be possible or cause timeouts. I wonder if also corruptions.

So, does anybody now I can force XFS (and the OS, in this case Centos 7) to re-read the file table without remounting?

Comment: XFS is not a cluster-aware filesystem. Use a proper network filesystem that supports being shared, such as NFS or GlusterFS.

Comment: Your use case matches CVMFS https://github.com/cvmfs/cvmfs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XFS isn't a cluster filesystem and therefore hasn't any facility to do what you're asking for (well, there existed a proprietary -- and expensive -- [clustered version known as CXFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CXFS), but that's another story).

The correct solution is to use a cluster filesystem. There are a lot of them, unfortunately generally quite complex to set up.

CentOS offers GFS2, which is quite difficult to set up IMO; I personally prefer OCFS2, which is extremely easy to set up and use on Debian and derivatives (and probably Oracle Linux, too), and offers very good performance, only lacking extended attributes and ACLs (which is usually of little importance in cluster setups anyway).

See for instance [this guide.](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/configure-gfs2-setup-cluster-linux-rhel-centos-7/)

Comment: CentOS also offers [gluster](https://www.gluster.org/) and [ceph](https://ceph.io/), both of which are much nicer to work with than GFS2.

Comment: @larsks gluster and ceph are *scale-out (or distributed) filesystems*, which are not identical to a cluster filesystem. While there is overlap, they generally are not a drop-in replacement for a cluster filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @wazoox! Yes, moving to a cluster filesystem is in the todo list at the expense of penalizing a bit the I/O performance and making all the system more complex.

Answer (score 4):

Please don't do that. As explained by [@wazoox answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1047098/269155) (which I upvoted) XFS is **not** a cluster filesystem.

At minimum you will have cache coherency issues, as described in your original question. However, if not mounting with `-o norecovery,ro` options (ie: *both* `norecovery` *and* `ro`) you **risk corrupting your filesystem.**

Please consider using NFS on a "master" node to export the storage to the other volumes. If you can't do that, you have two options:

- use a *cluster-aware filesystem* as GFS2 or OCFS2. A cluster aware filesystem supports multiple concurrent mounts from different running kernels, where each node has a dedicated journal (ie: "a window") for writing to the main filesystem. Be aware that the cache coherency required between the various nodes can significantly lower performance, especially when reading something that was already in another node cache;
- use a *scale-out, distributed filesystem* as Gluster, Ceph and the likes. The main difference between a cluster vs distributed filesystem is that the latter really is an *aggregation* between other filesystems, each local to a node. This aggregation is generally done via a user-space application (ie: gluster client) and it greatly impairs performance versus a classical local POSIX filesystem. However, you can aggregate tens or hundreds of nodes, with capacity and speed scaling as you add nodes.

While the only method to find the best approach for you specific case is to test the various approaches with a representative workload, I would suggest keeping things simple at first and to try with a NFS share.

Comment: Well, the thing is that we read many times and write not so often. And the reading nodes are connected through fibre to the storage which makes the operation quite fast. If we go through a single NFS point we will loose al that and the NFS server will be overloaded with > 500 simultaneous connections. So that is not a applicable in this case.

A cluster filesystem is probably the way to go in the future. We were considering BeeGFS (hardware vendor suggestion). But, of course, that complicates the whole system and we will loose a bit of performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can drop filesystem cache and trigger re-read as:

```
 echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: Yes, and completely kill performance of everything running on the node.

Comment: Which the umount/mount cycle likely already does, so that factor is already in play here.

Comment: Actually, this solution may be acceptable (even with the performance penalty) if we apply it not so often. I wonder if it may have some side effect (data corruption)

Comment: The risk of a data corruption is the same as during regular IO workloads. In your case it's almost zero, as file system is mounted as RO (well, you might of course have other IO related activities on that node).

Comment: Ok. I tested this solution yesterday and it worked. But I gave it a new try just now (node under higher load) and it is not working. No refreshing of the files in the filesystem.